# Python 2.7 argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have a function:

`def x(a,b,c)`

How can I collect variable values from the command line that fit this pattern?

`python test.py --x_center a --y_center b  c` (`c` has, for example, 3, 4 or more values )

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can do something like that like this:

```
import argparse

def x(x_center, y_center, values):
    print "X center:", x_center
    print "Y center:", y_center
    print "Values:", values

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Do something.")
    parser.add_argument('-x', '--x-center', type=float, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-y', '--y-center', type=float, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('values', type=float, nargs='*')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    x(args.x_center, args.y_center, args.values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Try it out:

```
$ python test.py --x-center 1 --y-center 2 3 4 5
X center: 1.0
Y center: 2.0
Values: [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

To use [the `argparse` module](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html), you'll normally want to start with a `main` function (and some boilerplate that calls it). In the `main` function, you'll want to [create an `ArgumentParser`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#creating-a-parser). After that, you'll want to add some arguments.

To add an argument, you use [`add_argument`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument).

```
parser.add_argument('-x', '--x-center', type=float, required=True)
```

Here, we're adding an option, `-x`, which also has a long option variant, `--x-center`. The `type` we pass to `add_argument` tells it to require it to be a `float` (and error if it's not a valid float). We also tell `argparse` that it's required; if it's not provided, error.

```
parser.add_argument('values', type=float, nargs='*')
```

This is just like before, but since the string we pass to it does not begin with a dash, it assumes it is not an option, but rather a non-option argument. Again, we tell it we want `float`s. `nargs` allows you to specify that it takes more than one argument. `*` specifies that we want any amount of arguments.

Finally, we parse the command line with [`parse_args`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args). This returns an object that we'll store.

You can then access the options and arguments on that `args` object and do relevant things in your program.

Comment: Line x(args.x_center, args.y_center, args.values)
has to change to 
x(args.x, args.y, args.values) in order to run correct

Comment: @VasileiosAntoniou: Are you sure about that? The code works as-is for me, and making your change breaks it.

Comment: Yes I'm sure but it doesn't matter. At least we both have a running code! :)